# Unable to build python 3.7.0 "_dbm" optional module

Tags: software-installation, gcc, python3, make

I've been able to successfully finish building python 3.7.0 but one last optional module keeps slipping through the net! `_dbm`

What ubuntu or debian package is required for this?

```
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_dbm
```

I've been able to include in the build `_gdbm` but not `_dbm`, why?
I have installed `libgdbm-dev` (which solved `_gdbm`) but can't definitively find any other `*dbm-dev` package that is relevant for `_dbm`.

I would really appreciate a hand if anyone knows what I'm missing!

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- gcc8.2
- python3.7.0 source
- using configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to satisfy the dbm requirement via this module

```
sudo apt install libgdbm-compat-dev
```

It looks like the older "dbm" files are moved to "gbdm-compat" package.

Comment: Worked with gcc 8.2.0 and python3.7.2!
Thanks @Senthil

Comment: Useful information helped me to build complete python3.8.3 on Ubuntu18.04. Thanks.

Comment: Worked on Kali Linux 2021.2 - built complete Python 3.9.5 with gcc 10.2.1

Comment: Still useful on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.10.0 with gcc 9

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 20.04 GCC 9.3.0 building Python 3.7.4

Comment: This was the missing piece for Ubuntu 22.04 (Linux Mint 21), GCC 11.3.0 and Python 3.8.12